# Graph Algorithms Question (Design and Analysis)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

[image]

I'm trying to design the algorithm and answer these two questions but can't produce a solution. I've tried drawing the pictures for the graph as well.

Comment: It would improve your Question if you stated a problem in your own words.  Posting the *image* of an assignment strongly suggests you expect Readers to digest the problems for you.  If you are having trouble parsing the assignment because the terminology is unfamiliar, start by tackling the vocabulary problem.  If you have experience with some path finding algorithms and encounter a difficulty in reworking those to the problem at hand, formulate a problem in those terms.  Etc.

Comment: You should type in the question instead of posting an image.  An image takes longer to download, is more difficult to view on small screens, and is not searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer the first question, since this looks like homework, and maybe that'll inspire you. For the first problem, a greedy algorithm would work. Suppose you are tracing a simple path through this graph and you and go to some vertex not yet visited. If at $v$ you find you've visited all its neighbors, then you know you've been to its $d$ neighbors and to $v$ so you've been to at least $d+1$ vertices. So you can just start tracing through the graph, visiting a different node each time chosen arbitrarily until you cannot visit a new node, at which point you stop.